Nested Balls and sequences in metric spaces. Looking for proof reference of an interesting result.
The proposition below is easy to demonstrate and I intend to use it in a short article for a journal dedicated to short articles.

Proposition. Let $(x_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a metric space $(X,d_{X})$. Let $(t_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a
sequence of scalars in $\mathbb{R}$ converging to
$t_{\infty}\in\mathbb{R}$. If $d_X(x_{k+1},x_{k})\leq t_{k+1}-t_{k}$,
then
$$     B[x_{0},t_\infty-t_0]\supset B[x_{1},t_\infty-t_1]\supset B[x_{2},t_\infty-    >. t_2]\supset \ldots \supset
> B[x_{k},t_\infty-t_k]\supset \ldots     $$


Edit.  10/28/2024 Note that the sequence $(t_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is necessarily increasing or non-decreasing for non-trivial results.

Question.  Which reference (book or journal article) contains the statement and proof of this proposition?
I already know how to prove the proposition.  However, I don't want to demonstrate this proposition in the article, even if it's a short proof. I'd rather refer the reader of the article to a reference (a book on metric spaces or an article in a journal) that contains the proof. Even if I change my mind and demonstrate the proposition in the article, I still want to refer the reader to a reference that contains a proof of the proposition.

Edit on 11/23/2024.
1) I was surprised by user Alex Rovsky's answer, which shows this result as a simple example of bases in a metric space.  And it is clear that from a topological point of view the concept of a majorizing sequence is superfluous.
2) I apologize for not mentioning that a statement of this result mentioning the notion of majorizing sequence is important in Numerical Analysis. Both for robustness and stability results and asymptotic analysis. I also apologize for not using the numerical methods tag earlier.
3) I'm inclined to award the bonus to user Alex Rovsky the day before the bonus expires. Unless more answers appear with older references that state the result using the notion of majorizing sequences.

In this way, I want to dispel any possibility of confusion in attributing the authorship or discovery of the proposition to me.
The proposition seems to me to be well known to authors who work with Newton's method and its modifications for solving equations. See for example Tapia. But they use the proposition without mentioning it explicitly or prove it indirectly in more powerful results.
I briefly had the answer to my question in front of my eyes for about 5 minutes. I thought I saved the article that referred to a book that contained the answer to this question.  Months later (and after formatting my computer), I looked for the article in my computer's backup folder and couldn't find it. I can't even remember the name of the author of the reference. All I know is that the reference was published between 1999 and 2024.

$t_k$ is increasing?

@Thomas yes.  The sequence $(t_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing.

Not sure why you include "complete" in the conditions, since the proof is just an application of the triangle inequality, which all metric spaces satisfy. (Ensuring the intersection of the nested closed balls is non-empty requires completeness, but that is not part of this proposition.)

As noted by Paul Sinclair, this follows almost immediately from triangle inequality. If you want to avoid demonstrating it in an article, you can just write "Immediate from triangle inequality" and unless this is a bachelor's thesis or something of the sort, I doubt any referee would give you any flak about it. You can also explicitly mention that it's folklore to dispel any illusion of originality. In general, I don't think there is any need to have citations for trivial propositions.

For each nonnegative $k$ put $r_k=t_\infty-t_k$. As far as I understand he proposition formulation (it seems there are a few typos there), it boils down that for each nonnegative $k$ we have the inclusion $B[x_k,r_k]\supset B[x_{k+1},r_{k+1}]$ of the open balls when $d_X(x_{k+1},x_k)\le r_k-r_{k+1}$. Then
I agree with the comments by Paul Sinclair
and tomasz and add to them that usually in papers even proofs of much more nontrivial facts are missed. But if you insist, I can provide the following reference from [Eng, page 248].

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space, $x_0$ a point of $X$ and $r$ a positive number; the set $B(x_0, r) =\{x \in  X : \rho(x_0,x) < r\}$ is called the open ball with centre $x_0$ and radius $r$ or, briefly, the $r$-ball about $x_0$. ... Let us also observe that if $x_1\in B(x_0,r)$, then $B(x_1,r_1)\subset B(x_0,r)$ for $r_1=r - \rho(x_0,x_1) > 0$. Indeed, if
$x\in B(x_1,r_1)$, then by virtue of (M3) we have
$$\rho(x_0,x) <\rho(x_0,x_l) +\rho(x_1,x) <\rho(x_0,x_1) +r-\rho(x_0,x_1) = r.$$

References
[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, General Topology, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

Thank's for your reply. Engelking's book really is an important reference. It describes the result I'm looking for, in an equivalent way, from the point of view of a topologist with brevity. I'm open to new references. That's why I'm going to wait a bit longer to give other answers a chance to be a bonus.

Engelking states the result without referring to the concept of a majorizing sequence. This is no demerit, since from a topological point of view the concept of a majorizing sequence is superfluous. However, for the purposes I need, it would be important for the statement to be written using the concept of majorizing sequences. From the point of view of numerical analysis, it's important.
